# git recommit image that it doesn't recognize changed (png w/ alpha space filled)

Tags: git, git-commit

Git doesn't recognize that some of my image files have changed.

In this case, it is a PNG that used to have alpha space, and now some of the alpha space is filled in with white pixels.

How do I force git to know this file is modified and commit it with accurate data? This is important because my build server isn't my local computer and needs the proper data from the git repository.

A convoluted solution I thought of is to remove the file, commit, push, put the file back in, commit and push. This seems messy and there has to be a better way.

I was also thinking of git mv -f and just renaming the file but I'm not sure if that will do it.

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried force adding the file:

```
git add -f image.png
```

Then commit, push etc

```
-f, --force
       Allow adding otherwise ignored files.
```

Comment: I did that and it doesn't add it to being staged, it doesn't see that there is a problem for me

Answer (score 0):

For me the following helped in these type of situations

```
git rm --cached path/to/file
git reset path/to/file
```

Make sure you take a copy of the file before running these two commands to avoid loss of your changes.

Comment: It works using just the first line, you only need to remove the cached file for git to recognize it changed